# How to access swift class variables that extends UIStackView from another class in Swift?

Tags: ios, xcode, macos, cocoa, swift4

I have a class called Text.swift, in this class I create my text fields then my another class, Buttons.swift, I want to access text in this class so that when I press the button the text in the text field can show up in textview area. But my problem is I could not call the Text class I tried something but then it assumes it is nil. I am beginner in swift so can you help me to call the class?

public class Text: UIStackView{

```
required public init(coder: NSCoder) {
    super.init(coder : coder)
    setUpTexts()
}

var textName = UITextField()
var textLastName = UITextField()
var textDepartment = UITextField()

private func setUpTexts(){
    //text field properties such as border width
    //then I added to my stack

}
```

}

class Buttons: UIStackView {

```
var buttonSave = UIButton()
var buttonClear = UIButton()
var buttonCancel = UIButton()
var textView = UITextView()
var anotherClass : Text!

var arrayName = [String!]()
var arrayLastName = [String!]()
var arrayDepartment = [String!]()

required init(coder: NSCoder) {
    super.init(coder : coder)
    setUpButtons()



}



private func setUpButtons(){

    buttonSave.setTitle("Save", for: .normal)
    buttonClear.setTitle("Clear", for: .normal)
    buttonCancel.setTitle("Cancel", for: .normal)


    buttonSave.addTarget(self, action: #selector(Buttons.btnSave(_:)), for: .touchUpInside)
    buttonClear.addTarget(self, action: #selector(Buttons.btnClear(_:)), for: .touchUpInside)
    buttonCancel.addTarget(self, action: #selector(Buttons.btnCancel(_:)), for: .touchUpInside)

    textView.isEditable = false


    addArrangedSubview(textView)
    addArrangedSubview(buttonSave)
    addArrangedSubview(buttonClear)
    addArrangedSubview(buttonCancel)


}


@IBAction func btnSave(_ sender : UIButton){


    arrayName.append(self.anotherClass?.textName.text)
    arrayLastName.append(self.anotherClass?.textLastName.text)
    arrayDepartment.append(self.anotherClass?.textDepartment.text)

    var sumText = " "
    for item in 0..<arrayName.count{
        sumText = sumText + "\(arrayName[item]!) \(arrayLastName[item]!)   \(arrayDepartment[item]!)\n" //to print each person line by line
    }
    textView.text = sumText */

}
```

I want to add my texts into these arrays.But it can not see it. I looked lots of stackoverflow questions but I could not find the right one.

Comment: how did you initialized anotherClass

Comment: I edited it,  sorry I did not change it . @Sh_Khan

Comment: in setUpButtons you must give a frame and init the Text

Comment: how can I do this like initialize the Text ? @Sh_Khan

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Can you try , When you create an object from Buttons custom `UIStackView` class , you must give it a frame or appropriate constraints

```
public class Text: UIStackView {

    required public init(coder: NSCoder) {
        super.init(coder : coder)
        setUpTexts()
    }

    public  override init(frame: CGRect) {
        super.init(frame : frame)
        setUpTexts()

    }
    var textName = UITextField()
    var textLastName = UITextField()
    var textDepartment = UITextField()

    private func setUpTexts(){

        distribution = .fillEqually
        axis = .vertical
        textName.backgroundColor = UIColor.red
        textLastName.backgroundColor = UIColor.blue
        textDepartment.backgroundColor = UIColor.orange
        addArrangedSubview(textName)
        addArrangedSubview(textLastName)
        addArrangedSubview(textDepartment)

    }

}

public class Buttons : UIStackView {

    var buttonSave = UIButton()
    var buttonClear = UIButton()
    var buttonCancel = UIButton()
    var textView = UITextView()
    var anotherClass = Text()
    var arrayName = [String!]()
    var arrayLastName = [String!]()
    var arrayDepartment = [String!]()

    required public init(coder: NSCoder) {
       super.init(coder : coder)
       setUpButtons()
    }

    private func setUpButtons(){

          distribution = .fillEqually

        buttonSave.setTitle("Save", for: .normal)
        buttonClear.setTitle("Clear", for: .normal)
        buttonCancel.setTitle("Cancel", for: .normal)


        buttonSave.addTarget(self, action: #selector(Buttons.btnSave(_:)), for: .touchUpInside)
        buttonClear.addTarget(self, action: #selector(Buttons.btnClear(_:)), for: .touchUpInside)
        buttonCancel.addTarget(self, action: #selector(Buttons.btnCancel(_:)), for: .touchUpInside)

        textView.isEditable = false

        textView.backgroundColor = UIColor.green

        addArrangedSubview(anotherClass)
        addArrangedSubview(textView)
        addArrangedSubview(buttonSave)
        addArrangedSubview(buttonClear)
        addArrangedSubview(buttonCancel)



    }
    @IBAction func btnSave(_ sender : UIButton){


        arrayName.append(self.anotherClass.textName.text)
        arrayLastName.append(self.anotherClass.textLastName.text)
        arrayDepartment.append(self.anotherClass.textDepartment.text)

        var sumText = " "
        for item in 0..<arrayName.count{
            sumText = sumText + "\(arrayName[item]!) \(arrayLastName[item]!)   \(arrayDepartment[item]!)\n" //to print each person line by line
        }
        textView.text = sumText

    }

    @IBAction func btnClear(_ sender : UIButton){

    }

    @IBAction func btnCancel(_ sender : UIButton){

    }

}
```

Comment: It works , just one last question you put it text field next to the buttons but I want my text field elsewhere I previously defined a stack  then how can I change its place

Comment: because you know they stuck in a very tight place  @Sh_Khan

Comment: change **axis = .vertical ** to **axis = .horizontal**

Comment: No I mean you add the buttons stack but I want to add in an another stack for example  at the bottom buttons and at the top of the page text fields and in the middle textview area @Sh_Khan